# Making the absolute constant in sub-gaussian characterization explicit

Tags: probability, probability-theory, distribution-tails

I have recently been reading Vershynin's "High-Dimensional Probability" (which can be found for free [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)), and I would very much like to find an explicit representation of the absolute constants found in the equivalent properties of sub-gaussian random variables when restated in terms of the sub-gaussian norm.

Following the proof of Proposition 2.5.2, stated below, I think it should be possible to say that $C \geq 12\sqrt{e}$ for the absolute constant in the proposition, since we get the relations
$$ K_2 \leq 3K_1, \quad K_3 = 2\sqrt{e}K_2, \quad K_1 = K_4 = 2K_5$$
and we can thus simply take the largest $C$ so that all relations are upheld, i.e. $C = 12\sqrt{e}$.

However, I would like to find the appropriate constants when restating these properties in terms of the sub-gaussian norm. From the Proposition it is apparent that we have $K_4 = \|X\|_{\psi_2}$, and so I would think we can simply take $K_1 = \|X\|_{\psi_2}$ as well, but in the book we have the following restatement of the properties:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(|X|\geq t) &\leq 2 \exp(-ct^2/\|X\|_{\psi_2}^2) \quad \text{for all }t\geq 0 \\
\|X\|_{L^p} &\leq C \|X\|_{\psi_2}\sqrt{p} \\
\mathbb{E}\exp(X^2/\|X\|_{\psi_2}^2) &\leq 2 \\
\text{if } \mathbb{E}X=0 \text{ then } \mathbb{E}\exp(\lambda X) &\leq \exp(C\lambda^2\|X\|_{\psi_2}^2) \quad \text{for all }\lambda \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}
So, basically I am wondering why we get a $c$ in the first property here... are these different constants? If so, why? And can we make them explicit?

---

For reference, this is the relevant proposition:

**Proposition 2.5.2**
Let $X$ be a random variable. Then, the following properties are equivalent; the parameters $K_i > 0$ appearing in these properties differ from each other by at most an absolute constant factor.

1. The tails of $X$ satisfy
   $$ \mathbb{P}(|X| \geq t) \leq 2 \exp (-t^2/K_1^2) \quad \text{for all } t \geq 0. $$
2. The moments of $X$ satisfy
   $$ \|X\|_{L^p} = (\mathbb{E}|X|^p)^{1/p} \leq K_2 \sqrt{p} \quad \text{for all } p \geq 1. $$
3. The MGF of $X^2$ satisfies
   $$ \mathbb{E} \exp (\lambda^2 X^2) \leq \exp (K_3^2 \lambda^2) \quad \text{for all } \lambda \text{ such that } |\lambda| \leq \frac{1}{K_3}.$$
4. The MGF of $X^2$ is bounded at some point, namely
   $$ \mathbb{E} \exp (X^2/K_4^2) \leq 2$$
   Moreover, if $\mathbb{E}X = 0$ then properties 1-4 are also equivalent to the following one.
5. The MGF of $X$ satisfies
   $$ \mathbb{E} \exp (\lambda X) \leq \exp (K_5^2 \lambda^2) \quad \text{for all } \lambda \in \mathbb{R}. $$

---

**Edit**

One of the constants was not too hard to get by using the implication $(3) \implies (4)$:

Since $K_4 = \|X\|$ we get $K_3 = \sqrt{\log2}K_4 = \sqrt{\log2}\|X\|$.

Comment: See chapter 2 of high dimensional statistics by wainwright. The constants are all there

Comment: @Andrew some are, yes, but the constants for the representation using the sub-gaussian norm are not, for example. In fact, Wainwright does not introduce the norm at all.